# Как посмотреть исходный код методов scale(), rotate(), translate() класса Graphics2D?

Tags: java, графика, методы

Из класса Graphics2D я использую методы `scale()`, `rotate()`, `translate()`.
Есть ли способ посмотреть полный исходный код этих методов, чтобы в дальнейшем я смогла использовать их логику и части кода?

Comment: Почитайте об аффинных преобразованиях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `java.awt.Graphics2D` - абстрактный и перечисленные методы у этого класса тоже абстрактные. Чтобы вам посмотреть реализацию, вам надо знать конкретный инстанс класса, который наследует `Graphics2D` и используется вами. Тогда вы сможете посмотреть исходный код.